# PayPal IPN postback failure

Tags: magento, paypal

I have recently upgraded my Magento live website from 1.6.2.0 to 1.7.0.0.
Starting after the upgrade, I now have a issue in PayPal Standard Payment.
When a customer pays by using PayPal, the payment on PayPal goes smoothly, but the Magento order state is not updated and stays in "pending" state.

I have checked various websites reporting this, but I can't still solve the problem.

I have the payment_paypal_standard.log reporting this:
"....
[postback_result] => 
[exception] => PayPal IPN postback failure. See paypal_unknown_ipn.log for details."

But I have no paypal_unknown_ipn.log being created, so I can't have more info about the error.

Investigating more, I have found the possible trouble is that the returning PayPal postback string is not correctly decrypted, but I have not found a real solution that help me to solve the problem.

Is there a way to find a solution shortly?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but if it's any consolation I am 99% positive that the PayPal IPN has some bugs in it and does not inform you or your scripts of purchases 100% of the time. I have processed a few thousand payments via IPN... and there are always 1 or 2 for every 100 that I have to manually process (by logging into PayPal and re-sending the IPN message, which then works fine) so I can only assume that they are not working properly.

Answer (score 3):

See http://doghouse.agency/article/debugging-paypal-ipn-postback-failures-magento

Basically, CURL sometimes decides to add a "Expect: 100" field to the postback request-header to check if it's allowed to send this request. This causes the CURL response string to be different than what Magento (up to 1.7) expects

Change

```
$response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 2);
$response = trim($response[1]);
```

to

```
$response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response);
$response = trim(end($response));
```

and it should fix this specific issue. Of course, you could be experiencing a different issue, ie a CURL error. In that case, log the CURL error number. See this page for a list of CURL error numbers: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but manually patch by

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=13515#30

See my comment #30.

hope this helps.
cheers