# PayPal IPN Retrying - Payment Pending Magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.9

We have recently move to Paypal Pro Hosted on Magento 1.9.2.1 and having an IPN issue. When a customer makes an order it stays as Pending Payment, even though the customer had paid. Have tried everything I can possibly think of including:

- Checked the IPN URL in Paypal and it was domain.com/paypal/ipn/
- Added IPN logs to see if there was anything in there causing the issue. http://inchoo.net/magento/debugging-paypal-ipn-in-magento/ (after doing this there is no errors in paypal_ipn_error.log - However there is in paypal_ipn.log, see below)
- Since we also accept payments in Paypal via virtual terminal (over phone) we created a centralised IPN listener (https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2015/04/orders-stuck-in-pending-payment-in-magento-due-to-paypal-disabling-ipn/) - this didn't fix the issue. The IPN URL is now domain.com/null_ipn.php
- The Order in Magento just says Pending Payment and there is no invoice generated.
- When checking Paypal IPN History it says Retrying with the error code 500.

This is from /var/log/paypal_ipn.log (added to try and debug - seen on inchoo's link above)

```html
2016-03-03T16:52:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): PayPal IPN POST data: Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 0.12
    [invoice] => 100855658
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [address_status] => unconfirmed
    [payer_id] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [tax] => 0.02
    [address_street] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW],
    [payment_date] => 08:50:44 Mar 03, 2016 PST
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [address_zip] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [first_name] => Oliver
    [mc_fee] => 0.12
    [address_country_code] => GB
    [address_name] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [business] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [address_country] => United Kingdom
    [address_city] => London
    [quantity] => 1
    [verify_sign] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [payer_email] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [txn_id] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [address_state] => London
    [receiver_email] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [payment_fee] => 
    [receiver_id] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [item_name] => 
    [mc_currency] => GBP
    [item_number] => 
    [residence_country] => GB
    [receipt_id] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
    [handling_amount] => 0.00
    [transaction_subject] => 
    [payment_gross] => 
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [ipn_track_id] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
)
```

This is from enabling debug mode in the Magento config:
/var/log/payment_hosted_pro.log

```html
2016-03-03T16:52:03+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    [BMCreateButton] => Array
        (
            [METHOD] => BMCreateButton
            [BUTTONCODE] => TOKEN
            [BUTTONTYPE] => PAYMENT
            [L_BUTTONVAR0] => subtotal=0.10
            [L_BUTTONVAR1] => tax=0.02
            [L_BUTTONVAR2] => shipping=0.00
            [L_BUTTONVAR3] => invoice=100855658
            [L_BUTTONVAR4] => address_override=true
            [L_BUTTONVAR5] => currency_code=GBP
            [L_BUTTONVAR6] => buyer_email=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR7] => discount=0.00
            [L_BUTTONVAR8] => billing_first_name=Oliver
            [L_BUTTONVAR9] => billing_last_name=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR10] => billing_city=London
            [L_BUTTONVAR11] => billing_state=London
            [L_BUTTONVAR12] => billing_zip=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR13] => billing_country=GB
            [L_BUTTONVAR14] => billing_address1=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR15] => billing_address2=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR16] => first_name=Oliver
            [L_BUTTONVAR17] => last_name=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR18] => city=London
            [L_BUTTONVAR19] => state=London
            [L_BUTTONVAR20] => zip=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR21] => country=GB
            [L_BUTTONVAR22] => address1=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR23] => address2=[HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [L_BUTTONVAR24] => paymentaction=sale
            [L_BUTTONVAR25] => notify_url=https://camerakings.co.uk/paypal/ipn/
            [L_BUTTONVAR26] => cancel_return=https://camerakings.co.uk/paypal/hostedpro/cancel/
            [L_BUTTONVAR27] => return=https://camerakings.co.uk/paypal/hostedpro/return/
            [L_BUTTONVAR28] => lc=GB
            [L_BUTTONVAR29] => template=mobile-iframe
            [L_BUTTONVAR30] => showBillingAddress=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR31] => showShippingAddress=true
            [L_BUTTONVAR32] => showBillingEmail=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR33] => showBillingPhone=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR34] => showCustomerName=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR35] => showCardInfo=true
            [L_BUTTONVAR36] => showHostedThankyouPage=false
            [VERSION] => 94.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => IWD_SI_Other_OnePage
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [WEBSITECODE] => <form action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HSSS-1a4Z7el1S2t72I5U7Cxl8cq2wy1HLac0--mAeIDBJYA6xiKNHSqkIohKb81o3D3ZvMghnw">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

            [EMAILLINK] => https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess?hosted_button_id=HSSS-1a4Z7el1S2t72I5U7Cxl8cq2wy1HLac0--mAeIDBJYA6xiKNHSqkIohKb81o3D3ZvMghnw
            [HOSTEDBUTTONID] => HSSS-1a4Z7el1S2t72I5U7Cxl8cq2wy1HLac0--mAeIDBJYA6xiKNHSqkIohKb81o3D3ZvMghnw
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-03-03T16:50:09Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => [HIDDEN ON STACKOVERFLOW]
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 94.0
            [BUILD] => 18316154
        )

    [__pid] => 27186
)
```

Is there something I am missing? It says [ACK] => Success so why is Magento not seeing this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151270/paypal-ipn-postback-failure